# Can Cat 5 cable be run in metal conduit?

Tags: conduit, ethernet

I want to run Cat 5 cable along the side of my home in 1/2 in. EMT Conduit.  I was considering actually pulling to Cat 5 cable in that conduit.  Will this cause any problems on a 100Mbps connection between a video camera and my GB switch?

Comment: In my honest opinion, if you want to run cabble, get yourself some cat 6 shielded cable.

Comment: Is there electrical power in that same conduit??

Answer (score 3):

As long as you're not running power in the same conduit or parallel to the conduit within about a foot you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Rob has already addressed the safety issue: don’t run low voltage and main wires in the same conduit.

But I think you are asking from a noise and bandwidth point of view.

**Noise** The EMT can act as an antenna. To avoid any interference take care to bond it to equipment ground at both ends.

**Bandwidth** Cat5 cable is rather out of date. I would never use less than Cat5e and probably your cost to go with Cat6 is minimal. If there is any chance down the road you plug a switch in where the camera is to wire up several cameras then you will prefer to have used better cable.  Unshielded twisted pair (UTP) is fine. Shielded is nice but more expensive and if you are putting this in a grounded conduit by itself then not much point.

Comment: Many people say Cat5 as shorthand for Cat5e. I don't even think you can find non-5e Cat5 cable anymore, unless you have some lying around from 20 years ago.